# How to get information in div with php api( curl or file_get_contents)

Tags: php, jquery

There is 1 empty HTML page. When you open it jquery write in page. HTML with 2 div looks like,

```
<div id=1>html1</div>
<div id=2>html2</div>
```

When u view using **F12**, then page its empty.(page is not empty but showing empty) and **curl** or **file_get_content** returning empty

my problem is how to get information in `div` with php api( curl or file_get_contents)

Sorry about my English. Please try to understand and help me.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that is not possible.

The curl request will not execute the javascript, so the HTML will not appear in the response.

What you might want to do is to use curl or file_get_contents to get the javascript which creates the HTML.